# pointers not pointing correctly and comparison warnings

Tags: c

the following short program asks user to enter # of hospital rooms (between 1-5), and asks for number of flowers, which cannot be a negative number.

Then, it picks based on how many rooms the price from the `hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[5]`, and it also displays the total flowers multiplied by $2.50 each.

finally, total cost of room(s) price + flower costs is added

heres the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>    

void getUserInput(int *numHospitalRooms, int *numFlowers);

int main()
{
    float hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[5]={300.00,350.00,400.00,450.00,500.00};
    int numHospitalRooms = 0;
    int numFlowers = 0;
    float flowerPricing = 2.50;

    getUserInput(numHospitalRooms, numFlowers);

    float flowerCost = numFlowers*flowerPricing;

    float totalCost = (flowerCost + hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[numHospitalRooms]);

    //

    printf("\nCost for %d room(s): $%.2f", numHospitalRooms, hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[numHospitalRooms]);
    printf("\nFlower(s) Cost: $%.2f \n", flowerCost);

    printf("\nTotal cost:  $%.2f", totalCost);

    return 0;
}

void getUserInput(int *numHospitalRooms, int *numFlowers)
{
    do {
        printf("\nHow many hospital rooms: ");
        scanf("%d", &numHospitalRooms);
        if (numHospitalRooms < 1 || numHospitalRooms > 5)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid number of rooms, room number must be between 1-5!\n");
        }

    }while((numHospitalRooms < 1 || numHospitalRooms > 5));

    do {
        printf("\nEnter number of flowers: ");
        scanf("%d", &numFlowers);

        if (numFlowers < 0)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid number of flowers, negative values are not accepted!\n");
        }

    }while((numFlowers < 0));
}
```

i am getting a lot of warnings when i compile:

- [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'getUserInput' makes pointer from
  integer without a cast

  [Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'

  [Warning] passing argument 2 of 'getUserInput' makes pointer from
  integer without a cast

  [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer

not only that, but entering a negative number isnt being taken into account at all in the `getUserInput()` conditional statements.

here is an example of the output:

> How many hospital rooms: 6
>
> Invalid number of rooms, room number must be between 1-5!
>
> How many hospital rooms: -1
>
> Invalid number of rooms, room number must be between 1-5!
>
> How many hospital rooms: 5
>
> Enter number of flowers: -1
>
> Cost for 0 room(s): $300.00 Flower(s) Cost: $0.00
>
> Total cost:  $300.00

---

what am i missing? why are the warnings coming up like that and messing with the program?

Comment: You should first fix your code to not produce warnings - they are quite clear in this case,

Comment: @UnholySheep Ive tried so many things, ive searched around since yesterday night about each of the warnings and what they mean. all examples i found where people who had char and strings comparison, so they just had to change double quotation to single quotation for comparison. but in my case, they are both ints! i dont see the issue??

Comment: They aren't both `int`s - your function expects `int*` and you are passing `int` - those two are clearly different types (also pretty much everything in your `getUserInput` function that uses those two parameters is wrong - you probably need to study up on pointers)

Comment: @UnholySheep ive been studying about them since yesterday...what else you want me to do? ive tried appresands, ive tried rereading the code logic and switching things around, it still not working :/

Comment: Randomly adding symbols is a bad way to try to fix code. You need to actually understand what the code does if you want to fix it - which is not what SO is for, this is not a debugging service. You should probably start with smaller code and make sure that that compiles without warnings and yields the expected results and only after that add more functionality - your function is completely broken right now (and invokes *undefined behavior*)

Comment: @UnholySheep riiight, which is exactly what i did before i used function prototype/pointers. i tested the code first all in the main, then i seperated them out. THATS where i started encoutering issues and I decided to seek SO. but apparently, it appears ive simply wasted my time posting here -_-

Comment: Because you shouldn't just test it in `main`  - I already told you your `getUserInput` is wrong, every single usage of the parameters inside it is wrong - try rewriting that function from scratch (without changing the parameter types) and make it first work without warnings (e.g.: have it just set fixed values for the two parameters that are passed in) - then you should quickly realize what your issue is

Comment: @UnholySheep even if i were to pass fixed values in, which i could easily do now, that still wont help me with the pointer issue. i already know the function wrong, which is why i said "missing something". i asked on here to get help from experts who could guide me and tell me what this "something" is. there's no reason to complicate it

Comment: @master ? - You can copy and paste text from your the output window. Much easier than capturing an image and post it. And you problem is still that you have to decide on `int` or `int*`. They are different and cannot be mixed.

Comment: You are not missing *something*, you seem to be misunderstanding just about *everything* about how pointers work - here's a little example of how to pass those parameters properly and assign them values inside the function: http://ideone.com/02Hrzs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much thinking, i finally figured it out:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void getUserInput(int *numHospitalRooms, int *numFlowers);

int main()
{
    float hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[5]={300.00,350.00,400.00,450.00,500.00};
    int numHospitalRooms = 0;
    int numFlowers = 0;
    float flowerPricing = 2.50;

    getUserInput(&numHospitalRooms, &numFlowers);

    float flowerCost = numFlowers*flowerPricing;

    float totalCost = (flowerCost + hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[numHospitalRooms - 1]);

    printf("\nCost for %d room(s): $%.2f", numHospitalRooms, hospitalRoomsPrices_Array[numHospitalRooms - 1]);
    printf("\nFlower(s) Cost: $%.2f \n", flowerCost);

    printf("\nTotal cost:  $%.2f", totalCost);

    return 0;
}

void getUserInput(int *numHospitalRooms, int *numFlowers)
{
    do {
        printf("\nHow many hospital rooms: ");
        scanf("%d", numHospitalRooms);
        if (*numHospitalRooms < 1 || *numHospitalRooms > 5)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid number of rooms, room number must be between 1-5!\n");
        }
    }while((*numHospitalRooms < 1 || *numHospitalRooms > 5));

    do {
        printf("\nEnter number of flowers: ");
        scanf("%d", numFlowers);
        if (*numFlowers < 0)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid number of flowers, negative values are not accepted!\n");
        }
    }while((*numFlowers < 0));
}
```

this should be like this: `getUserInput(&numHospitalRooms, &numFlowers);`

and this should be like this:

```
scanf("%d", numHospitalRooms); //no appresand
```

---

There was no need for all that back and forth for such a simple mistake anyone could have pointed out from here. As a student trying to learn, this feels very discouraging to have to fight for learning my mistakes. a simple two lines of code recommendation like i posted now would have shined a bright day here instead of a negative atmosphere.